# $f(x)$ = $\int_1^x \sin(\cos t)\,dt\,$

Tags: integration

let $f$:$ \left[\frac{-\pi}{2}\ , \frac{\pi}{2} \right]\to\ \mathbb R$ be the function defined by

$$f(x) = \int_1^x \sin(\cos t)\,dt\,$$
if $g$ is the inverse of  $f$, find $g^{\prime}(0)$.

I don't know how to solve $\int_1^x \sin(\cos t)\,dt\,$.

Comment: Luckily you don't need to. Just look for the derivative of the inverse

Comment: Use the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note that** at $x=1$, $\;f(x)=0$ also $f'(x)=\sin(\cos x)$ using  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Since $g(x)$ is inverse of $f(x)$ so $g(f(x))=x$

Now take Derivative on both side to obtain $g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)=1$

$\implies g'(f(x))=\dfrac{1}{f'(x)}.........(1)$

Now put $x=$ in equation $(1)$

Hence $g'(f(1))=\dfrac{1}{f'(1)}$

$\implies g'(0)=\dfrac{1}{\sin(\cos 1)}$

Answer (score 0):

I think your $f:[-\tfrac{\pi}{2},\tfrac{\pi}{2}]\to\mathbb R$ is not bijective and thus the inverse of $f$ doesn't exist.

For example, $10\in\mathbb R$ but $a\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ satisfying $f(a)=10$ doesn't exist.

This is because, supposing such $a$ exists, I have
\begin{align}
10
&=|10|\\
&=|f(a)|\\
&=\left|\int_1^a \sin(\cos t)dt\right|\\
&\leqq\left|\int_1^a|1|dt \right|\\
&=|a-1|\\
&\leqq|a|+1\\
&\leqq\tfrac{\pi}{2}+1\\
&<10
\end{align}
and this is contradiction.

---

However, if there is $Y\subset \mathbb R$ such that $f:[-\tfrac{\pi}{2},\tfrac{\pi}{2}]\to Y$ is bijective, $g'(0)$ can be calculated as @mathophile does. (But I don't know whether such $Y$ exists or not.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statements):

If $g$ is the inverse function of $f$

Then we have

$$
g'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}=\frac{1}{f'(g(x))}
$$

---

We also have $f'(x)=\sin (\cos (x))$, and notice that $f(1)=0$ and $g(0)=1$
, too.

So we have

$$
g'(0)=\frac{1}{f'(g(0))}=\frac{1}{f'(1)}=\frac{1}{\sin (\cos (1))}
$$